# How do I combine Plot and ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I have 3d data which I'm looking to combine into 2d function. I want to be able to easily evaluate the results.

I'm trying to do something like `Show[ListPointPlot3D[data3D],Plot[f[x],{x,0,10000}]]`. The direct approach with Show doesn't work since Mathematica doesn't know how to combine the two objects.

The x and y components of 3d points and the function are the same

How do I properly do it?

Comment: A minimal example including `data3D` and a `f[x]` would be useful. In a hurry, `Plot` returns a `Graphics` object and `ListPointPlot3D`a `Graphics3D`. Thus, you should create a 3D version of your `f[x]` and use something like `ParametricPlot3D` to combine both 3D graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, if you function is `f[x]=2*Sin[2*x]`, and assuming an arbitrary dataset in 3D, your combined plot, where `f[x]`is plotted in the plane `x=0.5` as `f[z]=2*Sin[2*y]`:

```
data3D = Transpose@(RandomReal[{#}, 100] & /@ {1, 5, 10});
parametricf = {0.5, t, 2*Sin[2 t]}; parplot = 
ParametricPlot3D[parametricf, {t, 0, 4}, 
PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]];
ptsplot = ListPointPlot3D[data3D, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015], ColorFunction -> Hue];
Show[{ptsplot, parplot}]
```

[image]